# What do the Word commands/keyboard shortcuts "LineSpacing" and "LineSpacingGallery" do?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, line-spacing

I was looking for a way to assign shortcuts to things like the Line Spacing Options dialog (or Paragraph dialog), Add Space Before Paragraph, and Remove Space After Paragraph.

As far as I can tell, none of these things are available to assign shortcuts to.  However, I do see two related items: "LineSpacing" and "LineSpacingGallery".

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts Dialog showing these two options]

"LineSpacing" seems to set line spacing for a selection to single-spaced and then another push seems to undo the change.

"LineSpacingGallery" does nothing that I can find.

What do these commands do?  Also, where could I find this information for myself besides posting on SU?

I see that LineSpacing is a [property in VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.paragraphformat.linespacing), but I don't think it's related to this command.  I can't find anything about LineSpacingGallery.

Comment: Try this   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-in-word-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2    ..... Keyboard shortcuts are well documented.

Comment: These are default mappings.  I'm asking about custom mappings.

Comment: I have not seen anything like that in Word in all the time I have use Word. Maybe look at Auto Hot Key for what you want.

Comment: Use styles. https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/customize-or-create-new-styles-d38d6e47-f6fc-48eb-a607-1eb120dec563

Comment: Learn styles. Use styles. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/stylesImportance.htm Here is an easy way to access them regardless of which tab is showing. https://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#StylesQATAddIn

Comment: Here is how to create and use keyboard shortcuts. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330 You can assign keyboard shortcuts to styles. Here is how to find what shortcuts are there: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/create-a-list-of-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft/7952be51-6a8e-4382-994c-e6632ba4cf35?tm=1589698042191 -- Again, learn and use styles.

Comment: Reformatting a document with styles is not a time-efficient choice for a document I just need to fix and submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LineSpacingGallery` is not officially documented, but it looks like the command that opens the "Line and Paragraph Spacing" Drop-down Menu from the ribbon:

[image: "Line and Paragraph Spacing" Drop-down Menu]

`LineSpacing` on the other hand toggles the last setting that was chosen from that same menu.

But both of them are of no use for what you want to achieve (the first one seems to need a mouse click to be of any effect, anyway).

### What is more interesting:

1. The `Indents and Spacing` dialogue is only one mouse-click away:
   [image]
2. Word has the following pre-assigned shortcuts:

- `Ctrl+1` Set single line spacing
- `Ctrl+2`Set double line spacing
- `Ctrl+5`Set 1.5 line spacing

Now, If you press `Ctrl+Alt+"+"`, and then one of those shortcuts, you'll see that the associated functions are called: `SpacePara1`, `SpacePara2`, `SpacePara15`.

There's also `Ctrl+0` which "Sets or removes 12pt of space before the selected paragraph". The corresponding function is `OpenOrCloseUpPara`.

Comment: `OpenOrCloseUpPara`, `OpenOrCloseParaAbove`, and `OpenOrCloseParaBelow` are I think the closest I'm going to come to what I want.  Would be cool if these were documented somewhere.