# Is there a way to show visible indications of line spacing in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, line-spacing

The "Show/Hide ¶" button can be used to show various formatting marks.

I frequently need to add, remove, or change the spacing between lines.  However, there is no equivalent view for line spacing.

This means I need to open the Indents and Spacing Dialog, which involves at least 2 or 3 mouse clicks.  Alternatively, I can use the Add Space Before/After Paragraph or Remove Space Before/After Paragraph buttons, which can save a click.

This feels random to me, since I often don't know if the problem is space after the previous paragraph, space before the current paragraph, or both.

In another [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1823617/what-do-the-word-commands-keyboard-shortcuts-linespacing-and-linespacinggalle), I asked about shortcuts for some of these things, which would ease the pain a little bit.

But what I'd really like is a way to see what's going on with line spacing without having to go into a dialog.  What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: The most coherent way is to [define different styles](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/customize-or-create-new-styles-d38d6e47-f6fc-48eb-a607-1eb120dec563) which you can then assign to the various paragraphs. The applied style is highlighted in the styles pane.

Comment: Learn styles. Use styles. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/stylesImportance.htm

Comment: which version of word are you using ?

Comment: Turning on grid lines under the View tab can also help with this, although I keep them off because they are annoying, to me. They do not print. Again, learn and use styles.

Comment: @1NN Microsoft® Word for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2310 Build 16.0.16924.20054) 32-bit

Comment: Reformatting a document with styles is not a time-efficient choice for a document I just need to fix and submit.

Comment: Use shift-F1 to open the Reveal Formatting pane. As you move through your text, you will see character and paragraph details (including spacing) in that pane.